# Does $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ have an aperiodic monotile?

Tags: co.combinatorics, infinite-combinatorics, tiling

For any set $S\subseteq \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}= \mathbb{Z}^2$ and $a\in \mathbb{Z}^2$, we set $a+S = \{a+s: s\in S\}$, where $+$ is the componentwise addition in $\mathbb{Z}^2$. Moreover, for any collection of subsets ${\frak S}\subseteq {\cal P}(\mathbb{Z}^2)$ we let $a + {\frak S} = \{a+S: S\in{\frak S}\}$.

We say that a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) ${\frak T}$ of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is a *mono-tiling* if for any $T_0\neq T_1\in {\frak T}$ there is $a\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ such that $T_0 = a + T_1$. We call the mono-tiling ${\frak T}$ *aperiodic* if for all $y\in \mathbb{Z}^2$ we have ${\frak T}\neq y + {\frak T}$.

Does $\mathbb{Z}^2$ have an aperiodic mono-tiling?

Comment: No rotation? And just the existence of mono-tiling, not whether a tile admits only mono-tilings?

Comment: For a long time \cal A (or whatever symbol in place of A) shows in MO LaTeX as a small square. This is very annoying. Can one fix this \cal malfunctioning?

Comment: @WlodAA: see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5508/did-mathcal-stop-working-properly

Comment: Usually an aperiodic monotile refers to one whose associated subshift (of all tilings) has no periodic points. The title could also be changed to "monotiling".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. A $2$-by-$2$ square $\{0,1\}^2$ can tile $\mathbb{Z}^2$ with just one period. So $\{0,2\}^2$ can tile $2\mathbb{Z}^2 \leq \mathbb{Z}^2$ with just one period. Break other periods in the other cosets.

Comment: I was about to post the same thing, but I feel that 2-by-2 square actually can not tile $\mathbb{Z}^2$ with only one period -- you can shift by the vector $(2, 0)$ (which you probably think of), but also by $(2, 1)$ (or some variant of it). But now that I think of it, it can be fixed by considering $\{0, 1, 2\}\times \{0, 1, 2\}$ and use some non-repeating sequence to make your argument actually work.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. The SFT is basically a union of a vertical and a horizontal one-dimensional binary full shift (with a bit of overlap).

Comment: If this was math.SE I'd have explained :)

Comment: Ah,  I'm stupid and your example actually work, I can't draw pictures apparently (although a little explanation might be better).

Comment: If an MO answer doesn't cause any headaches, what are we even doing. I'll add something later